# Xamarin Android: SOAP Webservice fails (401 Unauthorized) but my credentails are correct

Tags: soap, xamarin, xamarin.android, unauthorized

### Error in Xamarin.Android

I get the following error:

> {System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401:
>   Unauthorized  at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReceiveResponse
>   (System.Net.WebResponse response,
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage message,
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExtension[] extensions) [0x00055] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/SoapHttpClientProtocol.cs:273
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke
>   (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x000b8] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/SoapHttpClientProtocol.cs:365
>   at DSPFood.Droid.SOAP.scan.ShipGetNewBatchCode (System.String
>   scannerID) [0x00001] in C:\Projects\Projecten\DSP
>   Food\Solution\DSPFood\DSPFood\DSPFood.Droid\Web
>   References\SOAP\Reference.cs:389   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   DSPFood.Droid.SOAP.scan:ShipGetNewBatchCode (string)  at
>   DSPFood.Droid.DependencyServices.SoapService+d__13.MoveNext
>   () [0x00057] in C:\Projects\Projecten\DSP
>   Food\Solution\DSPFood\DSPFood\DSPFood.Droid\DependencyServices\SoapService.cs:290
>   }

### Working code in Console application

But when I run following code in a console application it works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var nc = new NetworkCredential("**", "**");
    var soapClient = new SOAP.scan();

    soapClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    soapClient.Credentials = nc;
    var response = soapClient.ProdGetNewBatchCode("");
}
```

> Response: "A000000086"

### Xamarin

```
public string ShipGetNewBatchCode(string macAddress)
{
    var retValue = "";

    try
    {
        var nc = new NetworkCredential("**", "**");
        var soapClient = new SOAP.scan();

        soapClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        soapClient.Credentials = nc;
        var response = soapClient.ProdGetNewBatchCode("");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return retValue;
}
```

> Exception: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Comment: Are you running your code on an emulator or physical device?

Comment: On a physical device

Comment: Did you ask for internet permissions in your manifest?

Comment: @Screech129 Yes I did

Comment: Did you try it in the real device. May be the android emulator network env problem.